# Getting GSON error "com.google.gson.JsonParseException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "28 May, 2015 11:18:52 PM"

Tags: java, gson

In my application in Prod environment i am getting below exception

```
2015-05-28 23:45:00,153 INFO  [concurrentScheduler_Worker-7] [EventHandlerService] [line : 124 ]  - exception {} 
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "28 May, 2015 11:18:52 PM"
    at com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultTypeAdapters.java:271) ~[gson-1.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultTypeAdapters.java:233) ~[gson-1.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.deserialize(JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.java:50) ~[gson-1.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationVisitor.invokeCustomDeserializer(JsonDeserializationVisitor.java:88) ~[gson-1.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.JsonObjectDeserializationVisitor.visitFieldUsingCustomHandler(JsonObjectDeserializationVisitor.java:117) ~[gson-1.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.navigateClassFields(ObjectNavigator.java:150) ~[gson-1.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:123) ~[gson-1.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.fromJsonObject(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:73) ~[gson-1.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.deserialize(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:51) ~[gson-1.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:495) ~[gson-1.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:444) ~[gson-1.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:396) ~[gson-1.4.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:372) ~[gson-1.4.jar:na]
```

Where as in my local when i am trying to reproduce this exception it is not coming. I am using Gson 1.4 to convert an object into Json String and vice versa.

Please help.

Comment: Show your code also.

Comment: are you sure you have the same system date settings in prod and local? also share your code

Comment: if prod is in different geo location than you, maybe default locale are different

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the local date format is different from the production. Try to set the dateFormat in your GsonBuilder, and use java.util.date in your model class.

GsonBuilder:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
.create();
```

Model class:

```
MyObject {
    public Date create_date;
}
```

Json example:

```
{"create_date":"2015-04-13 13:00:15"}
```